# SQL: How to display items from one table according to categories from another table, and counting the total items in each category

Tags: sql, database, delphi-xe2

I have two tables, a category table, and a items table. The category table have the following fields:

```
   project_No
   cat_ID
   cat_Description
```

The items table has the following fields:

```
  project_No
  cat_ID
  item_Id
  item_description
  item_Qty
  item_cost
```

Now I need to write a query that displays all the items for each category, but I also want to count the amount of items in each category

Now the output must first list the category before the items in that catgegory and then list all the items in that category, and giving a total for the amount of items in that category, then another category and the items, for example

```
  Beverages
     Coffee          $1.50     4
     Tea             $2.50     4
     Total Items               2        
  Tin Food
      Peas             $0.50   10
      Meatballs        $1      20
      total items              2
```

I need to write this SQL and place it inside my TADOQuery component in Delphi

Please can anyone assist me

Comment: For SQL questions it's best to post representative sample rows from each table and a pseudo-table of expected results.

Comment: And setting up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) is even better.

Answer (score 0):

Select category_table.Cat_Description, item_table.Item_Desctiption, SUM(Item_table.Item_Cost) as Total_Cost, SUM(item_Table.Item_Qty) as Total_Qty
From Items_table join Category_Table 
on items_Table.Cat_Id = Category_Table.Cat_Id and items_Table.Project_no = Category_table.Project_no

This would get you the result:

Beverages   Coffee   $1.50  4
Beverages   Tea  $2.50  4
Tin Food    Peas     $0.50  10
Tin Food    Meatballs    $1.00  20

I summed your cost, but if you just want cost listed, remove the sum from the option.

Comment: The only thing that is missing from this answer is that after each category, for example beverages, that must also be a total items, that must count the number of items in each category

Comment: Personally, I would probably put it in Excel and do a pivot table, but there maybe a better way to do that.

Comment: I have considered using virtual tables as I do not think I will be able to get the result I want without using a virtual table